# Cannot use a required namespaced class

Tags: clojurescript

I have:

```
(ns test-1.core
  (:require [goog.dom :as dom]
            [goog.ui.Popup :as popup]
            [goog.positioning.AbsolutePosition]
            [rum.core :as rum]))
```

Now I can:

```
(dom/getElement "popup")
```

but for reasons I don't understand I cannot do :

```
(popup. .....)
```

Instead, I have to write:

```
(goog.ui.Popup. .....)
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/ui/popup.js) of `goog.ui.Popup` you can see that it is a class. This means instead of including it with `:require`, we need to use `:import`.

```
(ns test-1.core
  (:require [goog.dom :as dom])
  (:import [goog.ui Popup]))

(Popup. (dom/getElement "popup"))
```

Overall, use `:import` for Closure classes and enums, and use `:require` for everything else.